# How to increment a number in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to increment a number in a string.

My model:

```
public partial class updown
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(updown viewModel)
{
    var lastPO = db.updowns
                   .OrderByDescending(o => o.number)
                   .Select(m => m.number)
                   .FirstOrDefault() ?? "00001";

    item.number = lastPO++; // I get an error on this line
    db.updowns.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The error:

> Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

Expected result:

```
item.number // "00002"
```

## Update

Based on the now-deleted comments, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(updown viewModel)
{
    var s = db.updowns
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.number)
              .Select(m => m.number)
              .FirstOrDefault() ?? "00001/S2";

    var lastPO = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(s.Length - 5 - 3, s.Length - 3)); // *
    item.number = "EMOC-" + (++lastPO).ToString("00000");
    db.updowns.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Expected result:

```
item.number // "EMOC-00002/S2"
```

But I get an error on the line marked `// *` when I run it the second time.

Comment: Improved the clarity of your question. Still need help?

Comment: So what is the error the second time? When you run the debugger, what is the value passed to `Convert.ToInt32()`?

Comment: @Kuujoe36 I've posted my earlier comment as an answer.

Comment: ya, I change a little bit, `Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(5, 5))` and solve my problem @aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing a little bit of your code. It seems fine
[image]

i think the problem lies in here

```
var s = db.updowns
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.number)
              .Select(m => m.number)
              .FirstOrDefault() ?? "00001/S2";
```

the `?? "00001/S2"` might be triggering the error. try doing a break point in `var s` ... and see if all of s.number has value or has a correct convertible value (there could be just letters which can't be converted)

Answer (score 0):

> Expected result:
>
> ```
> item.number // "EMOC-00002/S2"
> ```

You need `+ "/S2"` here:

```
item.number = "EMOC-" + (++lastPO).ToString("00000") + "/S2";
```

## Explanation

What happens when you ran previous code the second time is that `var s = "EMOC-00002"` so `s.Substring(s.Length - 5 - 3, s.Length - 3)` gives `"OC-00"` instead of `"00002"` string, which `Convert.ToInt32()` cannot handle.